# How can I pass props to React components conditionally?

Tags: reactjs

I'm setting up various line charts using recharts with React. In order to keep the appearance consistent, I've created a component called MyLineChart, which takes an object containing formatting and required data like this:

```
const lineChartInfo = { // Pass in the required data, and some formatting info
  data: {
    values: this.state.userData,
    dataKey: "x",
    connectNulls: true,
  },
  xaxis: {
    dataKey: 'date',
  },
  yaxis: {
    domain: [1,7],
  }
}
```

To add a Chart to my app I then call:

```
<MyLineChart chartData={lineChartInfo} />
```

Within my MyLineChart component, I have the following render component:

```
render () {

        let chartData = this.props.chartData.data
        let chartXAxis = this.props.chartData.xaxis
        let chartYAxis = this.props.chartData.yaxis

        return (

            <LineChart data={chartData.values}>
                
                <XAxis 
                    dataKey     = {chartXAxis.dataKey} />
                <YAxis
                    .... ? this is where the issue is ..... />
                <Line 
                    stroke={STYLES.CHARTBLUE} 
                    strokeWidth={2}
                    dataKey={chartData.dataKey}
                    type="monotone"  />

              </LineChart>
        )
    }
```

For the YAxis, I want to pass in the domain if it's in the lineChartInfo object, and otherwise I want to pass in a default value.  I've tried to do it like this:

```
<YAxis
   { chartYAxis.domain ? `domain = {chartYAxis.domain}` : null } />
```

and like this:

```
<YAxis { if (chartYAxis.domain) domain = {chartYAxis.domain} } />
```

which various combinations of `, ${ etc, but I'm getting an error no matter what I do.  The error says "Expecting ..."

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?  I know I could enclose the entire `<YAxis>` in the curly brackets, but I have a few settings that will be like this, so I'd like to be able to handle them all separately.

Comment: Hey Sharon, you need to do this: `<YAxis domain={chartYAxis.domain || null } />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case when you have different props to send on the basis of a condition, you can try something on the lines of this :

```
<YAxis domain = { chartYAxis.domain ? chartYAxis.domain : null } />
```

In case when you have to pass props only if certain condition is true/false, you should try :

```
<YAxis domain = { chartYAxis.domain || null } />
```

Comment: `<YAxis domain = { chartYAxis.domain || null } />`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. Thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass dynamic props.

**Like this**

```js
const yAxisProps = {
  domain: chartYAxis.domain || null
}
<YAxis {{ ...yAxisProps }} />
```

Comment: this won't even compile. you could pass it with single quotes, but it won't work neither